# Draw a border around arrow-shaped mask

Tags: ios, swift, mask

In my app I need a contour of an arrow that will get filled with color as user progresses through some activity. To create an arrow shape in my view I've subclassed UIView for use in Interface Builder:

```
@IBDesignable
class MaskedView: UIView {

    var maskImageView = UIImageView()

    @IBInspectable var maskImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            maskImageView.image = maskImage
            maskImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            maskImageView.frame = bounds
            mask = maskImageView
        }
    }

}
```

Then in IB I select an arrow image, which creates the needed shape:

[image]

[image]

Here the view has gray background for demonstration purposes. Actually I need it to be white with arrow appearing as a black contour:

[image]

So basically I need a border around my arrow mask. What is the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: Use UIBezierPath to create a path object.

Comment: Let me know, if my answer is working?

Answer (score 1):

`yourView` should be in `clearColor`. Adjust `CGPoint` as per ur need with the help of `extension`.

```
let arrow = UIBezierPath.arrow(from: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100), to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 50),
                                       tailWidth: 10, headWidth: 25, headLength: 40)
let caLay = CAShapeLayer()
caLay.path = arrow.cgPath
yourView.layer.mask = caLay

let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
borderLayer.path = arrow.cgPath // Reuse the Bezier path
borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
borderLayer.lineWidth = 5
borderLayer.frame = greenview.bounds
yourView.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)



extension UIBezierPath {

    class func arrow(from start: CGPoint, to end: CGPoint, tailWidth: CGFloat, headWidth: CGFloat, headLength: CGFloat) -> Self {
        let length = hypot(end.x - start.x, end.y - start.y)
        let tailLength = length - headLength

        func p(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: x, y: y) }
        var points: [CGPoint] = [
            p(0, tailWidth / 2),
            p(tailLength, tailWidth / 2),
            p(tailLength, headWidth / 2),
            p(length, 0),
            p(tailLength, -headWidth / 2),
            p(tailLength, -tailWidth / 2),
            p(0, -tailWidth / 2)
        ]

        let cosine = (end.x - start.x) / length
        let sine = (end.y - start.y) / length
        var transform = CGAffineTransform(a: cosine, b: sine, c: -sine, d: cosine, tx: start.x, ty: start.y)
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addLines(between: points, transform: transform)
        path.closeSubpath()
        return self.init(cgPath: path)
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought of it, but actually was hoping to avoid manual drawing in terms of it being error-prone and hard to customize for AutoLayout. I was wondering if there's a way for swift to create UIBezierPath from image shape. It does recognize the shape when creating a mask, so why not draw a path around it with given line width, I thought )

Comment: Besides, there is a good chance the arrow shape will change in future versions. It can become more complicated, e.g. imitating feathers on the bottom. That will require 20-40 points to manage.